# Responsive collapsible sidebar using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to build a sidebar like W3 Schools website. For example if the screen max-width will 456px then sidebar will be hide and a menu icon would display. On click of menu icon sidebar will open.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FT3Cv.png)

Here is my code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: arial;
}


/* body{
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 100vh;
    } */

.navbar {
  top: 0px;
  left: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

.navbar-brand {
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 19px;
  padding: 0.2em 0.7em;
  color: white
}

.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item {
  display: inline;
}

.navbar .livestock-logo {
  background: white;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 1px;
  width: 60%;
}

.navbar ul li:hover {
  background: #3f612e;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px !important;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px !important;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px !important;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px !important
}

.navbar ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}

.navbar ul li {
  display: flex;
  left: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(235, 232, 232);
}

.navbar ul li a {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 25px;
  font-size: 0.8em !important;
  color: #000000;
  display: block
}

.navbar ul li a .fas {
  width: 20px !important
}

.navbar ul li a .far {
  width: 20px !important
}

.navbar-nav .nav-item a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.navbar ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none
}

.toggle-collapse {
  float: left;
  width: 45px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: transparent;
  /* color: white; */
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

toggle-collapse:hover {
  color: white
}

@media screen and (max-width:456px) {
  .navbar-brand {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
  }
  .toggle-collapse {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .navbar-nav {
    color: white;
    padding: 0%;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
  }
  .navbar-collapse {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: left;
    height: 0vh;
    transition: all 499ms ease;
  }
  .collapse {
    height: 100vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<style type="text/css">
  body {
    background: rgb(247, 247, 247) !important;
  }
</style>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"> {% load static %}
  <meta name="viewport" content="device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/responsive.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- <div>
            <button class="toggle-collapse">
                <img src="../static/images/toggle.png">
            </button>     
        </div>    -->
  <nav>
    <div class="navbar">
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"></a>
      <button class="toggle-collapse">
                    <img src="../static/images/toggle.png">
                </button>
      <div class="navbar-collapse">
        <div class="livestock-logo">
          <img src="../static/images/livestock.png" alt="livestock">
        </div>
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#"><img src="../static/images/home.png"> Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#"><img src="../static/images/home.png"> Index</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#"><img src="../static/images/home.png"> Users</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#"><img src="../static/images/home.png"> Companies</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#"><img src="../static/images/home.png"> Logout</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#"><img src="../static/images/search.png"> Search</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
<script src="/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../static/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudfare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.toggle-collapse').click(function() {
      $('.navbar-collapse').toggleClass("collapse");
    })
  })
</script>

</html>
```

I am unable to remove the white navbar.
Any help will be highly appriciated.

Comment: If it is simply a case of removing that white background, instead of using `#ffffff` for your the background, you could try `rgba(255,255,255,0)` which is also white but the `0` makes it transparent. With that particular value you can go up by `0.1` increments all the way to `1` which is no transparency at all.